# Is Firebase onAuthStateChange supposed to automatically trigger a page redirect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-router-v4

My app requires a series of Redux dispatches upon a user's login. Those dispatches must complete before the user is redirected to a page based on the status of the store. Through some debugging, what I have found is that it seems that after the user logs in and triggers Firebase's onAuthStateChanged listener, the page is automatically redirecting the user to the login page (which is then being redirected by react-router as it should) instead of when I declare the redirect. **Is there a way to prevent this behavior?**

At first, I thought the redirect was being triggered by the dispatches, but after some debugging, I narrowed the behavior down to the authentication change. I can verify that everything works as expected once the user is already authenticated and performs a page refresh.

```
// A bunch of imports before this

const store = configureStore()

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
)

let hasRendered = false

const renderApp = () => {
    if (!hasRendered) {
        store.dispatch(setApi()).then(() => {
            ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'))
        })
        hasRendered = true
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoadingPage />, document.getElementById('app'))

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log('logged in')
        store.dispatch(login(user.uid))
        await store.dispatch(startGetProfiles(user.uid))

        const profiles = store.getState().profiles
        const selectedCharacterId = localStorage.getItem('selectedCharacterId')
        const profileId = selectedCharacterId || profiles.length === 1 && profiles[0].id

        if (profileId) {
            await store.dispatch(startSetProfile(user.uid, profileId))
        } 
        const profile = store.getState().profile

        renderApp()

        if (!!profile.id) {
            history.push('/profile')
        } else if (profiles.length > 0) {
            history.push('/select')
        } else {
            history.push('/create')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('logged out')
        store.dispatch(logout())
        renderApp()
        history.push('/')
    }
})
```

I expect the page redirect to only occur when I use history.push('/somepage'), but instead the redirect is triggering immediately after the user logs in.

Comment: "Is Firebase onAuthStateChange supposed to automatically trigger a page redirect?" Nope. It isn't and it doesn't. If you put a breakpoint on `if (user) {` does it get triggered when you run the code in a debugger? If so, when you step through the rest of the method, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Welp, I just learned how to _actually_ debug, so thanks for that. After digging into it, it seems that the page refresh is occurring immediately after the `store.dispatch(login(user.uid))` call. Also, it turns out that the `history.push('/')` call in the else block is not necessary as the page redirects after `store.dispatch(logout())` call, which would seem to reinforce my suspicion that firebase is triggering a page refresh after executing a sign in / sign out process.

Comment: That's very unlikely, but of course not impossible. Can you try reproduce it with just the Firebase Authentication SDK on a site like jsbin, so I can have a look? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on minimizing the code needed to reproduce a problem, and why that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's what I learned - it seems that what is going on is that when a prop in my routes is changed, a refresh is occurring. All of my routes look something like the following:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({
    isAuthenticated,
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props} />     
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )} />
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth && !!state.auth.uid
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

Notice how I'm using Redux to check whether or not the user is authenticated before routing them. When the calls to dispatch a login/logout action to my store update the auth value, this updates the route prop of `isAuthenticated`, thus triggering an update of the component and the routing chain. In order to address this, I had to basically create new routes to handle what the router was doing upon the update and to remove the `history.push()` calls from my `onAuthStateChanged` code.

**So to answer my question, Firebase is not triggering page redirects. When using Redux in tandem with React-Router, be wary of changes to your route props that could trigger components to update and re-routing to occur.**